# Update multiple existing rows with php without PATCH?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Currently I'm quite unexperienced with php but needed a little simple program. I've created a little website where some data can be stored (The name of a product, the amount of those products and the price of that products)

I've called it back as a table with in every table row an input(text) field with the containing data.

I need this data to be editable and all be saved with just one press on the button but I just can't get it to work...;(

Here's my current code:

```
$products_array = array("");
$amounts_array = array("");
$prices_array = array("");
$id_array = array("");

<form method="POST" name="update">
    <?php
    foreach($object as $objects){
        array_push($products_array, $objects['product']);
        array_push($amounts_array, $objects['amount']);
        array_push($prices_array, $objects['price']);
        array_push($id_array, $objects['id']);

        echo "<tr>
           <td><input type='text' name='".$objects['id']."' value='". $objects['product'] ."'></td>
           <td><input type='text' name='".$objects['id']."' value='". $objects['amount'] ."'></td>
           <td><input type='text' name='".$objects['id']."' value='". $objects['price'] ."'></td>
        </tr>";
    }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Opslaan">
    </form>
```

this receives all the rows from the database in text fields and store their data in an array.

This is how I tried to update it:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
        for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
            $sql = 'UPDATE objects SET product = "$products_array[$i]", amount = "$amounts_array[$i]", price = "$prices_array[$i]" WHERE id = "$id_array[$i]" ';
            $sql = $conn->query($sql);
        }
        unset($_POST);
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Anyone has any clue how to fix this or has a better method?

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: you should be inserting POST values in to the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to uniquely identify each product details i.e. it's name, amount and price by it's id to perform the update operation. So **the solution** would be like this:

- There's no need to declare separate arrays for each attribute of a product, only `$object` array is enough to solve this problem.
- Your `<form>` should be like this: (Look closely at the `<input>` elements)

  ```
  <form method="POST">
      <table>
      <?php
      foreach($object as $objects){
          ?>
          <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="objects[<?php echo $objects['id']; ?>][product]" value="<?php echo $objects['product']; ?>" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="objects[<?php echo $objects['id']; ?>][amount]" value="<?php echo $objects['amount']; ?>" /></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="objects[<?php echo $objects['id']; ?>][price]" value="<?php echo $objects['price']; ?>" /></td>
          </tr>
          <?php
      }
      ?>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" name="update" value="Opslaan">
  </form>
  ```
- And this is how you can process the form to perform the `UPDATE` operation.

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['update'])){
      foreach($_POST['objects'] as $id => $products_array){
          $sql = "UPDATE objects SET product = '" . $products_array['product'] . "', amount = '" . $products_array['amount'] . "', price = '" . $products_array['price'] . "' WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";
          $sql = $conn->query($sql);
      }

      // your code

  }
  ```

---

**Sidenotes:**

1. If you want to see the complete structure of `$_POST['objects']`, do `var_dump($_POST['objects']);`
2. Your query is susceptible to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Always **prepare**, **bind** and **execute** your queries to prevent any kind of SQL injection. Here's a good SO Q/A on [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this completely fixed everything. It's kinda hard to understand for me at this point, but gladly you've added some information about why it is susceptible to SQL Injections and how I can fix it and why this works. This entirely fixed everything <3